# Moving data from rows to columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following:

```
  | 0           | 2                            |
  |-------------|------------------------------|
1 | Sale Date   | 3/5/2020                     |
2 | Case Number | CJ-19-2858                   |
3 | Plantiff    | Lakeview Loan Servicing, LLC |
4 | Defendant   | Tom                          |
5 | Address     | 111 Looper                   |
6 | Sale Date   | 3/5/2020                     |
7 | Case Number | CJ-18-7039                   |
8 | Plantiff    | FNB Community Bank           |
9 | Defendant   | Sally                        |
10| Address     | 123 Oak                      |
11| Sale Date   | 3/5/2020                     |
12| Case Number | CJ-18-5109                   |
13| Plantiff    | FNB Community Bank           |
14| Defendant   | Bill                         |
15| Address     | 545 Main                     |
```

How do I re-sort that into a dataframe like this?:

```
| Sale Date | Case Number | Plantiff                     | Defendant | Address    |
|-----------|-------------|------------------------------|-----------|------------|
| 3/5/2020  | CJ-19-2858  | Lakeview Loan Servicing, LLC | Tom       | 111 Looper |
| 3/5/2020  | CJ-18-7039  | FNB Community Bank           | Sally     | 123 Oak    |
| 3/5/2020  | CJ-18-5109  | FNB Community Bank           | Bill      | 545 Main   |
```

Comment: See question 10 in duplicate link.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as writing `df.T`

Comment: No, it isn't...

Comment: what else are you seeing beside a transposition?

Comment: It's pivot. See my comment under the question.